# Finding password protected .ZIP files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

We want to search the .ZIP files on our system to find out which have been password protected using 7zip (AES 256 encryption) and which have not. As far as I can tell, there is no built-in indicator, flag, property etc. which labels files as password-protected or not.

All the existing questions resulted in people using DotNetZip, but this was distributed on CodePlex which has now been archived - the file I can download from there does not seem to include the `Ionic.Zip.dll` which I believe is the part I need ([e.g. this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741442/check-if-a-zip-file-is-password-protected)).

Likewise, there are popular versions on gitHub and nuGet, which only contain other DLLs (`Ionic.Copy.dll` and `Ionic.IO.JunctionPoint.dll`), which I don't think are correct.

It sounds like I in fact need the DotNetZip DevKit to use the particular tool I want in Powershell, but I can't find a popular/reputable/updated download for this.

Is there another way to achieve what I need, or am I doing something wrong with how I'm trying to access DotNetZip?

Comment: It sounds like you want the 7Zip SDK.  Have you tried https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html to see if it opens your files?  The PKZip compression is builtin to .net in later versions.  No addins or extras required.  -- this comment based on current info as of date of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Found a post by one Igor Pavlov:

7z l a.7z -slt > list.txt
and look
Encrypted = +
and / or
"7zAES"
in "Method ="

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you give some more information about what this is doing? Is this using 7z's 'test' operation? I tried using the test operation and it took a very long time for an unencrypted file, and seemed to run forever for an encrypted one.